# How to intercept subqueries in mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I would like to log sql statements execution time. To do this I'm using interceptor plugin. However it only "catches" the outer statement and prints combined time needed to execute the whole statement including subqueries contained in `@Result`. Why does it not log all the statements separetely and is there any solution for this?

Here is the code reproducing my scenario:

**ADao:**

```
@Select({
        "select * from a",
        "where id = #{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}"
    })
@Results({
        @Result(column="id", property="id", jdbcType=JdbcType.INTEGER, id=true),
        @Result(column="id", property="bs", javaType=List.class, many=@Many(fetchType=FetchType.EAGER, select = "org.BDao.selectByAId")),
        @Result(column="id", property="cs", javaType=List.class, many=@Many(fetchType=FetchType.EAGER, select = "org.CDao.selectByAId"))
})
A selectByPrimaryKey(Integer id);
```

**BDao:**

```
@Select({
    "select * from b",
    "where a_id = #{aId,jdbcType=INTEGER}"
})
@Results({
    ...
})
List<B> selectByAId(Integer aId);
```

**CDao:**

```
@Select({
    "select * from c",
    "where a_id = #{aId,jdbcType=INTEGER}"
})
@Results({
    ...
})
List<C> selectByAId(Integer aId);
```

**Interceptor:**

```
@Intercepts({ @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "query", args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class, RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class }) })
public class LogTimeQueryExecutePlugin implements Interceptor {

    static int MAPPED_STATEMENT_INDEX = 0;
    static int PARAMETER_INDEX = 1;
    static int ROWBOUNDS_INDEX = 2;
    static int RESULT_HANDLER_INDEX = 3;

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogTimeQueryExecutePlugin.class);

    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object proceed = invocation.proceed();
        MappedStatement ms = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[MAPPED_STATEMENT_INDEX];

        logger.info("Execution time "+ms.getId()+" : "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)+" ms");

        return proceed;
    }

    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
    }

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {

    }
}
```

**Log:**

> Execution time org.ADao.selectByPrimaryKey : 59033 ms

Answer (score 0):

Try `StatementHandler.class` instead of `Executor.class`.

```java
@Intercepts({
        @Signature(type = StatementHandler.class, method = "query", args = { Statement.class, ResultHandler.class }),
        @Signature(type = StatementHandler.class, method = "update", args = { Statement.class })
})
public class StatementHandlerPlugin implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Object intercept(final Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        // just for simplification, use safer way
        val stmt = (StatementHandler) invocation.getTarget();
        val boundSql = stmt.getBoundSql(); // contains sql, parameterObject, parameterMappings ...
        // rest of implementation
    }
 
    // omitted
    
}
```